# java - how to get the jar files of a library or framework

Tags: java, jar, apache-camel, mvn-repo

I want to download the `.jar` file of a java framework.
That `.jar` should of course contain all the `.class` files that I need for my project.

I tried downloading from here:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core/3.18.2 
But the `.jar` file is only 4KB big and contains only meta information, but no java classes.
I found `jar` files with java classes in them in older versions, but in newer versions they seem to upload only meta information.

So I don't know how to get to the `.jar` file with all `.class` files inside.
I don't want to work with `maven` or `gradle` for now.
And you can't just download jars with maven or gradle you have to build your entire project with it.

I also searched the github (https://github.com/apache/camel) and source code of the "Apache Camel" project and did not encounter `jar` files.
Is there any other popular place where open source java frameworks/libraries with `jar` files can be found?

Comment: `I don't want to work with maven or gradle for now.` Why not? The framework might consist of multiple artifacts, and will surely depend on other libraries. All these dependencies are listed in the pom or grade build files. Do you really wish to manually list all the files, and download them one by one. And repeat that on every update or conflict with your other libraries for the project? The whole point of build tools is to do all this for you. Technically if you wanted to, you could just create a pom and use the `maven-depedency-plugin` with goal `copy-dependencies` to just get the jars.

Comment: Do use maven or gradle.

Comment: @slindenau I don't like the folder structure of `maven`/`gradle`. They create way too much folders.

Comment: And how would I even know which dependencies I need? If I had the `jar` file I could at least look for the `.class` file that I need.

Comment: You can customize Gradle to use any folder structure you like. I believe Maven allows this too, but it might be more work. However, seriously, the default layout of Maven and Gradle is pretty much the industry standard, and I suggest getting used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apache camel module doesn't contain any code. It just declares a list of dependencies, in the `/META-INF/maven/org.apache.camel/camel-core/pom.xml` file:

- camel-core-engine
- camel-core-languages
- camel-bean
- camel-browse
- camel-cluster
- camel-controlbus
- camel-dataformat
- camel-dataset
- camel-direct
- camel-directvm
- camel-file
- camel-health
- camel-language
- camel-log
- camel-mock
- camel-ref
- camel-rest
- camel-saga
- camel-scheduler
- camel-seda
- camel-stub
- camel-timer
- camel-validator
- camel-vm
- camel-xpath
- camel-xslt
- camel-xml-jaxb
- camel-xml-jaxp
- slf4j-api

You have to download the jars that you need in this list of dependencies. All jars can be found on https://mvnrepository.com/.

This is why everyone will recommend you to use maven or gradle, as those tools will manage the dependencies for you.